# How to change sql code to informatica process

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, informatica

```
*FROM 
(
SELECT adr_link.* 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ENTITY_ID,ENTITY_TYPE ORDER BY     EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC,SYS_CREATION_DATE DESC) AS RN
FROM ADDRESS_NAME_LINK adr_link
WHERE adr_link.LINK_TYPE IN ('B','A') 
  and adr_link.EXPIRATION_DATE is null 
)*
```

this is the part of sql code. I have to change this code to informatica process. I don't understand what is this code mean and I don't know which I should choose informatica transformation function

expectantly I don't understand this line below

```
*ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ENTITY_ID,ENTITY_TYPE ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC,SYS_CREATION_DATE DESC) AS RN*
```

Comment: You can use SQL in Informatica, so I don't really understand your question.

Comment: How to explain a window function easy???.... Well i can try its a special kind of aggregation as you can aggregate within GROUPS (so called PARTITION) without decreasing your resultset what GROUP BY would do..

Answer (score 0):

Here, read some [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [explanation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/sql-window-functions-introduction/). There are some examples. Next, write few queries to give it a try and a better understanding. It seems you need to fill some gaps before proceeding with your task.